# what happens to the records if record owner is inactivated or deleted from the org

Tags: sharing, owd

I have private sharing mode (OWD) for a custom object. Thus, only record owners have access to their respective records. Now one of the owner (user) needs to be deactivated. how to handle the records owned by him?
What is the conventional way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Thanks @RobGTX for the response. However, I want to check on the fact when you said "Anyone above that user in the Role Hierarchy will still have access, even if the owner is inactive"  I think that is only temporary and the access in role hierarchy also ends as soon as the sharing settings are recalculated. Please confirm if you agree?

Answer (score 2):

Anyone above that user in the Role Hierarchy will still have access, even if the owner is inactive.

Ultimately you will want to reassign these records to a new user.

You can do this 1-by-1 by simply changing the record owner
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_about_transfer.htm&type=5

to transfer everything at once, use the Mass Transfer tool
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_transfer.htm&type=5